# Java: Skipping the first line of user input when appending a text file?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filewriter, printwriter

So I'm trying to accept lines of text from the user so that it can be appended to a txt file. However, after the program runs, the first line the user entered does not appear in the appended file.

Here is a portion of the code:

```
System.out.println("enter advice (hit return  on empty line to quit):");
String advice = keyboard.nextLine();

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(inputFile, true);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

for(int n = 1; n <= 2; ++n)
{
  advice = keyboard.nextLine();
  pw.print(advice);
}

pw.close();
keyboard.close();
```

Here is a sample run of the code:

```
$ java Advice
enter input filename: Advice.txt **enter**
1: fully understand the given problem
2: do analysis and design first before typing
enter advice (hit return  on empty line to quit):
a **enter**
b **enter**

Thank you, goodbye!
$ cat Advice.txt
1: fully understand the given problem
2: do analysis and design first before typing
b
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: But in your example, the first line is the one starting with 1, right? That is in the file, or isn't it?

Comment: Correct, "1: fully understand the given problem 2: ..." is already apart of the txt file, and I want to append lines of text to it that the user enters.

Answer (score 2):

The first line the user enters is being captured but not being written to the file. 
`String advice = keyboard.nextLine();`
When you write to the file you are taking in the next user input